# Importing files in the header

Tags: xcode

I was wondering if I could import a header file, but not include any of that header file's included headers.

Suppose I have Class A that imports Class B. In Class B, I import Class C. Is there any way I can hide Class C from Class A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that: once you import a file, all its imports come in as well.

However, if you want to use only `ClassA`, you can *forward-declare* it in your own header, instead of importing `ClassA`'s header:

```
@class ClassA;
```

Now you can make variables of type `ClassA*`, use `ClassA*` as return type or a parameter type, etc. At the same time, dependencies of `ClassA`'s header will not be loaded.

In general, it is a good idea to reduce the number of headers that you import inside your header, for example by moving imports related to implementation (rather than the interface) into the .m file, and using *class extensions*.

Comment: Alright, thank you. In "class B", I'm basically trying to subclass the UINavbar and set a custom image to it, but I want it to be something that only shows in that view. The problem is that I have to import "class B" in "class A" and what ends up happening is that class A ends up with the dynamic image as well. I'm trying to do this in iOS 4, so it's turning out to be a hassle :/